# SQL query to find max primary key with custom format

Tags: sql, database

I have a data table which the primary key is formatted like M00001, M00002, M00003 ... so on. They are all string type. Is there any way to query the database to find the max primary key?

Comment: Are you saying you want the maximum numeric part of the key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select max(id)
from t
```

If the RDBMS does not support `max()` then:

```
select id
from t
order by id desc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The exact syntax will differ depending on which DBMS you are using.
In sql server for keys of one letter followed by five digits assuming you want to keep the leading zeros

This is T-SQL, so Sql Server. Substring or an equivalent is waht you are looking for.

```
Select Max(SubString(id,2,5)) From t
```

t-sql isn't chock full of string functions but there's a fair few, and you can usually glue a few together to get what you want.